Is the time complexity of Levenberg-Marquadt algorithm polynomial?
I'm trying to use Scipy's least_squares function and the documentation says that least_squares uses the Levenberg-Marquadt algorithm.

Method ‘lm’ (Levenberg-Marquardt) calls a wrapper over least-squares algorithms implemented in MINPACK (lmder, lmdif). It runs the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm formulated as a trust-region type algorithm.

I was wondering whether the time complexity Levenberg-Marquadt algorithm is polynomial or not. If not, are there any polynomial algorithms that also solves "non-linear least square" problem, like Levenberg-Marquadt? I tried searching on Google but nothing works.

Strictly speaking, no. But in practice, almost certainly.
The Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm is a hybrid of Gauss-Newton and gradient descent. Each pass is polynomial in the size of the input, so the question is how many iterations it requires to converge. Or, perhaps, whether it converges at all.
You can run L-M with any model function $f(x,\boldsymbol\beta)$, where $\boldsymbol\beta$ is the vector of parameters. By the no free lunch theorem, L-M does no better than any other method when averaged over all possible model functions.
Having said that, L-M has some desirable properties for well-behaved model functions. Gauss-Newton has quadratic convergence. Gradient descent has exponential convergence; specifically, the expected error is proportional to $e^{-2i/\sqrt{\kappa}}$, where $i$ is the iteration number and $\kappa$ is the condition number.
So for well-behaved models, L-M does take polynomial time to converge. For your model, you may need to prove it.

Are there any ways to prove that my model is well-behaved? For my context, it's a multivariate blackbox function but it is polynomial and doesn't contain any other operators except addition, subtraction, exponents(variable raised to a constant only) and multiplication

@DavidPham Polynomials are probably fine, although they can have zeroes in weird places.
